# How can i access the inlying properties?

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I have a perl variable like this. **How can i access the inlying properties (like '706')?**

```
my @config = [
        {
        'x' => [ 565, 706 ],
        'y' => [ 122 ],
        'z' => 34,
        'za' => 59,
    }
];
```

**EDIT:**  `print Dumper($config[0]);` yields : `$VAR1 = undef;`

Looks like i get acces using `$config[0][0]->{x}[1];`. Why do i have to use [0][0] (one is clear, but he ssecond...)?

**EDIT2:**  I am sorry for changing the data structure, but the definition which was given to me changed.

Comment: For the answer to this (and much, much more) you need the [Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

Comment: Not sure that the comma after `59` is really correct.

Comment: no the comma seems to be no problem

Comment: One of the nice things about Perl is that the closing comma is optional. Which means that you can leave it there and not have to worry about adding it when you need to add more items.

Comment: If you had "use warnings" turned on then Perl would tell you why $config[0] is undef. $config[0] is the first element from the array @config. But you don't have an array called @config, you have an array _reference_ in $config. So you need to use $config->[0].

Comment: no, using "use warnings" it does not say why - there is no warning at all, but $config->[0] shows 'x'

Comment: @Thariama: If you continuously change your data structure, it will be a little bit hard to answer correctly. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**EDIT:** *Follow the shifting problem definition.*]

Given:

```
my @config = ( 
  [
    { # NB: insertion order ≠ traversal order
        "x"  => [ 565, 706 ],
        "y"  => [ 122 ],
        "z"  => 34,
        "za" => 59,
    },
  ],
);
```

Then this will do it:

```
# choice §1
print $config[0][0]{"x"}[-1];   # get 1ˢᵗ row’s xᵗʰ row’s last element
```

understanding of course that that is merely syntactic sugar for:

```
# choice §2
print $config[0]->[0]->{"x"}->[-1];   # get 1ˢᵗ row’s xᵗʰ row’s last element
```

and that that is just syntactic sugar for:

```
# choice §3
print ${ $config[0] }[0]->{"x"}->[-1];   # get 1ˢᵗ row’s xᵗʰ row’s last element
```

which in turn is just syntactic sugar for:

```
# choice §4
print ${ ${ $config[0] }[0] }{"x"}->[-1];   # get 1ˢᵗ row’s xᵗʰ row’s last element
```

which again is syntactic sugar for:

```
# choice §5
print ${ ${ ${ $config[0] }[0] }{"x"}}[-1];   # get 1ˢᵗ row’s xᵗʰ row’s last element
```

and that, of course, is equivalent to:

```
# choice §6
print ${ ${ ${ $config[0] }[0] }{"x"} }[ $#{ ${ ${ $config[0] }[0] }{"x"} } ];   # get 1ˢᵗ row’s xᵗʰ row’s last element
```

Comment: You need $config->[0]{"x"}[-1]. The difference between $config[0] and $config->[0] is important.

Comment: @Thariama: It now matches your current (but not previous) problem definition. I have included your data structure in my answer in case you go changing it again.

Comment: @daveorg: Not any more I don’t. She changed her variable from a scalar to an array.

Comment: @tchrist: I think that at least part of the problem here is that the OP doesn't actually know what data structure she has :-)

Comment: problem was that this definition changed indeed - sry for that (i am a 'he' btw)

Answer (score 4):

Your variable is equivalent to :

```
my $config = [
    'x', [ 565, 706 ],
    'y', [ 122 ],
    'z', 34,
    'za', 59,
];
```

So if you want to get the 706, you can do:

```
print $config->[1][1];
```

**Updated according to new data in the question**

With the updated question, you can access now by :

```
say $config->[0]{x}[1];
```

**New update according to new data structure**

According to the last updated data structure you provide:

```
my @config = [
        {
        'x' => [ 565, 706 ],
        'y' => [ 122 ],
        'z' => 34,
        'za' => 59,
    }
];
```

you assign an anonymous array [...] that contains itself a hash {...}
to an array @config, this will populate the first element of @config
with the anonymous array

```
say Dumper \@config;

$VAR1 = [
          [
            {
              'y' => [
                       122
                     ],
              'za' => 59,
              'x' => [
                       565,
                       706
                     ],
              'z' => 34
            }
          ]
        ];
say $config[0][0]{x}[1];  #prints 706
```

I think you want to do either:

```
my $config = [
        {
        'x' => [ 565, 706 ],
        'y' => [ 122 ],
        'z' => 34,
        'za' => 59,
    }
];
say $config->[0]{x}[1]; #prints 706



my @config = (
        {
        'x' => [ 565, 706 ],
        'y' => [ 122 ],
        'z' => 34,
        'za' => 59,
    }
);
say $config[0]{x}[1];  #prints 706
```

Comment: I much prefer the output of `Dumpvalue` over that of `Data::Dumper`.